# Accessing Dictionary values inside a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to replicate some functionality found in MATLAB in python and am looking for a pythonic way to solve this problem.

Consider the following example.

```
import io
import csv

data = """name,age,height
scott,31,175
bob,45,180
george,2,100
"""

f = io.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
fields = next(reader)
table = []

for row in reader:
    item = dict(zip(fields, row))
    table.append(item)
```

Some data is imported, each row is an item in a list and each column is paired up with it's field name in a dictionary.

Accessing a single field of a specific element is simple

```
>>> table[1]['name']
'bob'
```

How can I return all values of the 'name' field in the table aside from using either a for loop or a list comprehension?

```
ages = [x['age'] for x in table]
```

In MATLAB I could do the following

```
ages = [table(:).age]
```

which would return an array containing everyone's age.

Is there a way to return all of the elements of a single field from a list of items? Or is the list comprehension the best way?

[EDIT]:How about if I want to access only the first 2 elements and get their fields? Or the last 2 elements?
List Comprehension still the best way to go?

Perhaps there is a better data structure to allow this?

Comment: What is wrong with the list comprehension?

Comment: What if I only want to select 'only the last 3 items'?

Comment: You should probably be using a pandas `DataFrame` for this.  It is the equivalent of a MATLAB table (in fact MATLAB tables are based on either pandas dataframes or a similar data structure from R).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is your best bet for creating your list.

That said, you should be using a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of the vanilla `reader` in your code:

```
...
f = io.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.DictReader(f) # default delimiter is ,
table = list(reader)

ages = [x['age'] for x in table]
names = [x['name'] for x in table]
```

Comment: What if I only want to select 'only the last 3 items'? Can I use slicing to get only the age field of the last 3 items for example?

Comment: Yes, why not. `[x['age'] for x in table[-3:]]`

Comment: Guess I was hoping for a more succinct syntax. Does the job though!

Comment: Well, if you wrote the entire code in matlab, reading the strings into objects and all, I'm not sure you'll get something crispier than this :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative approach if you are wanting to do more complex things with tables then there is `pandas` which is basically programmatic spreadsheet for Python:

```
>>> f = io.StringIO(data)
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f)
>>> df.age
name
scott     31
bob       45
george     2
Name: age, dtype: int64
>>> df.age.values
array([31, 45,  2])
>>> df.age[-2:]
name
bob       45
george     2
Name: age, dtype: int64​
>>> df.index
Index(['scott', 'bob', 'george'], dtype='object', name='name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `collections.defaultdict()` as:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for data in table:
    for k, v in data.items():
        d[k].append(v)
```

`d` will contain the list of all values as `key`. For example, for accessing all the *ages*, do:

```
d['ages']
```